# Are there drawbacks to resizing mesh renderer bounds?

Tags: unity, rendering, mesh

I had a problem yesterday where some of the meshes were not visible. I figured out the problem, which was that the mesh renderer bounds were not in the cameras field of view.

So, in order to make the mashes visible, I'm thinking of either making the bounds of the mesh renderer larger, or moving them forward so they are in the camera view.

If I do this, are there any drawbacks, like potential glitches, problems, more strain on the system, etc that might happen?

Comment: What led to your mesh bounds being separated from your visible mesh in the first place? This might be the better root issue to solve.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm not too sure.The mesh is a FPS character, and it starts off in a hands at side kind of pose, so the mesh is off camera in the beginning. I have animations that make the mesh go on screen (raising fists, drawing weapons, etc). When the mesh moves during the animation, the bounds/box stays in it's original location, which makes the mesh invisible in the camera view.